# NoClassDefFoundError from Bash Script

Tags: java, bash

I am currently trying to run my application from within a bash script. When I run the java application from the console it works fine. I have compliled the java app and have tried multiple different commands within the script, and cannot figure it out. I am fairly new with scripting so I am guessing it something syntax related. I have also read multiple different posts on here but nothing seems to work.

Here is my script and I am running it as sh endpoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH=json-simple-1.1.jar:log4j-1.2.17.jar:.
result=$(java -cp $CLASSPATH com/api/endpoint/MyApp $INI)
echo $result
```

The error I am getting is as follows

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/api/endpoint/MyApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.api.endpoint.MyApp
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
Could not find the main class: com/api/endpoint/MyApp.  Program will exit.
```

The application is in a package of com.api.endpoint and is in that directory. I have a feeling this is something simple that I am overlooking, but I have been struggling with this for a few days now. Any ideas?

Full script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the search path for the shell to be the standard places.
PATH=setting the path here; export PATH

# Config file
INI=config.ini

# Log function
function log()
{
timestamp=`date +"%s"`
echo "$timestamp:$1">>$ERROR_LOG_FILE 
}

# Read config file
if [ -f $INI ]
then
    source $INI
else
    exit 1 # terminate the script and return error
fi

# create error log file
echo -n "" > $ERROR_LOG_FILE

# prepare the WLST env to execute api list python script
source $WLST_SCRIPT

# call list.py
result=$(java wb.WLST $WLST_PYTHON_SCRIPT)

if [[ $result == *Exception* ]]
then
  log "$result"
  exit 1 # terminate the script with error code
fi

# prepare the java env to execute region inventory java app
PATH="/tmp/:$PATH"; export PATH
#echo $PATH

CLASSPATH=json-simple-1.1.jar:log4j-1.2.17.jar:.
result=$(java -cp $CLASSPATH com/api/endpoint/MyApp $INI)
echo $result
```

Comment: What is `$INI`? You can run those *exact* commands manually from the same directory and have it work?

Comment: I think the main class argument used '.' notation: `com.api.endpoint.MyApp`

Comment: What does `find . -name 'MyApp*'` return?

Comment: @Arkadiy is correct. Use `java com.example.Foo`, not `com/example/Foo`

Comment: I would also put quotes in, as `CLASSPATH="..."` and `java -cp "$CLASSPATH" ...` It doesn't matter in this case since there are no spaces, but it's a good habit to get into with shell scripts.

Comment: tried using the "." notation and received the same results. There is a lot of other content within the script, and I believe (and now see) that the script is setting a java env that is not the same and screwing up by the time it gets to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are separated by a period (`.`), not a slash (`/`), so:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH=json-simple-1.1.jar:log4j-1.2.17.jar:.
# Note the classname:
result=$(java -cp $CLASSPATH com.api.endpoint.MyApp $INI)
echo $result
```